# How i can partially specialize my class template to int_<...>, long_<...>

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11

may be something like

```
template <class C>
struct apply<template<> struct T<C N>>
{
    typedef typename T<N + 1>::type type;
};
```

just for example it returns next integral constant type.

Comment: I don't get what your question is.. Hope I'm not the only one :)

Comment: i want to have template specialization for int_<some_integer>, long_<some_long> and other such types. it seems to be very tricky.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Rather than responding to comments, you should edit your question to clarify it. [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, yet concise. The question isn't currently understandable because you haven't given the declaration for the template you want to specialize. Also, the question should appear in both the title and the body.

Comment: some people understand, some not, hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed type you can specialize directly:

```
template <typename> struct apply;  // primary template

template <unsigned int N>
struct apply<int_<N>>
{
    typedef int_<N + 1> type;
};
```

You can also specialize on templates that take one integer parameter:

```
template <template <unsigned int> class TInt, unsigned int N>
struct apply<TInt<N>>
{
    typedef TInt<N + 1> type;
};
```

The latter will match *any* `template <unsigned int> class`, though, so be careful.

Comment: +1, thanks is it possible to do something like this: **template <class C, template <C> class TInt, C N>**

Comment: @Yola: I don't understand your syntax. What is that supposed to be? Template arguments must be either types, objects, or templates.

Comment: i still to write generic class for every of integral constant classes, but its seems to be too tricky for me now if possible. Thanks, and apply.